# Removing Leading White Space from XML Doc

Tags: php, xml, atom-feed

Our company web site generates feeds, but for some reason, white space is being injected before the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` tag, making it invalid XML.

How do I trim out this white space, or better yet determine where this space is being created?

Example of a feed from the site is this (from the blog page):
http://www.centerline.net/feeds/gateway.php?action=returnFeed&k=atom&q=&f=0,1,0,0,0,0&c=0,35,0,0,0,0&s=0,0,0,0,0,0,1&st=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like your site is using PHP, you can use PHP's ltrim(...) function to trim leading whitespace from a string.  Here is the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php